# Relation between the roots of a function

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials, roots

I have this question from my exam where it's asked to find the sum: $$S=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(1-r_k)^2}$$
where $r_k$ are the roots of
$$f(x)=x^n-2x+2\quad,n\ge3$$
I recalled this relation
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x-r_k}$$
and quickly realised that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$
and using derivative would easily produce my answer. Indeed
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right)=\frac{f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2}{f(x)^2}=-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(x-r_k)^2}$$
Evaluating at $x=1$ gives
$$S=\frac{(n-2)^2-n(n-1)}{1^2}=4-3n$$
However after the exam I realised that I have no ideea why
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x-r_k}$$
and I just memorized it, is there a nice way to show it? 
And of course maybe a more elegant solution to this exam question?

Comment: Are you aware of the Newton-Raphson Method?

Comment: Never heard of, but thanks I will google it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

$$f(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n)$$

Using logarithm,

$$\ln (f(x))=\ln (x-r_1)+\ln(x-r_2)+\cdots +\ln(x-r_n)$$

Taking derivative,

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}= \frac{1}{(x-r_1)}+\frac{1}{(x-r_2)} +\cdots +\frac{1}{(x-r_n)}$$

Done!

Comment: The issue with this post that Joonas Ilmavirta points out in his own answer can be fixed simply by replacing $\ln(\,)$ with $\ln |\,|$ everywhere.

Comment: But then the function may not be differentiable any more. @Paul

Comment: In that case can't we just split ln|x-a|  into ln(x-a) when x>a and ln(a-x) when x<a. Derivating first gives $$\frac{d}{dx}ln(x-a)=\frac{1}{x-a}$$ and $$\frac{d}{dx}ln(a-x) = \frac{1}{a-x}(a-x)' =\frac{1}{x-a}$$ So $$\frac{d}{dx}ln|x-a|=\frac{1}{x-a}, x \neq a$$

Comment: @Zacky Yes, you can use the absolute value of the logarithm if you want to. I prefer the algebraic approach without logarithms because you don't have to worry about differentiability and having everything well define, and the same method works for complex polynomials with no changes. The logarithm is a bit of a mess over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta - I was the one noting that your issue with this answer is solved by using log of the absolute value. Zacky was just pointing out that the claim that this made the function not differentiable is false. Log of the absolute value is an anti-derivative of $1/x$ across the entire real line except $0$, where both are undefined. When $\Bbb C$ is brought in as you suggest, your issue loses merit, because then one can define the logarithm on negatives, indeed all of $\Bbb C$ except some ray from $0$, which can be chosen to miss all roots of $f$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry; it was indeed you who pointed that out. When it comes to defining complex logarithms, it's worth noticing that the formula $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$ is no longer true in general. If you want $\log(f(x))$ to behave nicely, you want $f(x)$ to avoid the branching set for all $x\in\mathbb C$, and that's unfortunately impossible.

Comment: @Joonas $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$, doesn't hold true, I agree, but there is a constant factor of $2n\pi$ which vanishes on taking derivative.

Comment: Actually, the logarithmic derivative is a linear operator in itself, with nice properties. One does not need to go through the problematic step of writing $\log(f(x))$.

Answer (score 33):

While Jaideep Khare's computation with the logarithm gives a good quick way to memorize or derive the result, there is an issue:
The logarithms of negative numbers are not defined if one works over the reals, and care must be taken with branches if one moves to the complex plane.
When $r_k$ is fixed and $x$ ranges through all the reals, $x-r_k$ will inevitably get negative values.

Here is a way to prove the desired result without resorting to logarithms:
By the fundamental theorem of algebra a polynomial can be written in terms of its roots and a coefficient $a\in\mathbb C$ as
$$
f(x)
=
a(x-r_1)\cdots(x-r_n).
$$
The coefficient of $x^n$ is $a$ and in your case you know it to be $1$, but it is unimportant.
The derivative can be computed by differentiating each term in the product in turn:
$$
f'(x)
=
a(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n)
+
a(x-r_1)(x-r_3)\cdots(x-r_n)
+
\dots
+
a(x-r_1)\cdots(x-r_{n-1}),
$$
where in the $n$th term of the sum the $n$th term of the product has been dropped.
When $f(x)\neq0$, it is easy to divide each term of $f'(x)$ by $f(x)$, and we get
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
=
\frac{1}{x-r_1}
+
\frac{1}{x-r_2}
+\dots+
\frac{1}{x-r_n}.
$$

The result and the proof are also applicable to complex polynomials, whereas with logarithms $f(z)$ will always hit the branching set of the logarithm, no matter how you choose it.
Also, $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$ is not true in general for complex $a$ and $b$.

Finally, let me emphasize that this result holds for a polynomial function $f$ (with roots counted with multiplicity), not for all functions in general.
In your question you are working with polynomials but you speak about "functions", so beware of generalizing the result beyond what's true.

Comment: The trick with the log is slick, but I have to give the point to this answer, since it's more general.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach, which is longer but would also work for more general symmetric expressions in the roots, is to use Vieta's formulae.

If a polynomial $f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1 x + a_0$ has roots $r_1, r_2, \dots, r_k$, then the ratio $-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$ gives us the sum $r_1 + r_2 + \dots + r_k$.

To turn this into the sum we want, we should modify $f(x)$ slightly.

First, $f(t-x)$ has roots $t - r_1, t - r_2, \dots, t - r_k$.

Second, $f(t-1/x)$, though it is not a polynomial, is still zero when $x = 1/(t-r_1), \dots, 1/(t-r_k)$.

However, multiplying through by $x^n$ gives the polynomial $x^n f(t-1/x)$ which has roots at $1/(t-r_1), \dots, 1/(t-r_k)$.

To apply the Vieta's formula we want to use, it remains to figure out the coefficients of $x^n$ and $x^{n-1}$ in 
$$
  x^n f(t-1/x) = x^n a_n (t-1/x)^n + x^n a_{n-1} (t - 1/x)^{n-1} + \dots + x^n a_1 (t-1/x) + x^n a_0.
$$
To get a multiple of $x^n$ from a term $x^n a_k (t-1/x)^k$, we have to choose the $t^k$ term of the binomial expansion of $(t-1/x)^k$. This tells us that the coefficient of $x^n$ in this polynomial is
$$
   a_n t^n + a_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \dots + a_0 = f(t).
$$
To get a multiple of $x^{n-1}$ from a term $x^n a_k (t-1/x)^k$, we have to choose the $\binom k1 t^{k-1}(-1/x)$ term of the binomial expansion of $(t-1/x)^k$. This tells us that the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in this polynomial is
$$
   - a_n \cdot n t^{n-1} - a_{n-1} \cdot (n-1)t^{n-2} - \dots - a_1 = -f'(t).
$$
Putting these together, we get that the sum of the roots of $x^n f(t-1/x)$ is
$$
   \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{t-r_i} = \frac{f(t)}{f'(t)},
$$
as desired.

(For the specific case of the polynomial $f(x) = x^n - 2x + 2$, this would go faster since we wouldn't have to derive the general formula.)

Answer (score 0):

In general, if 
$$f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x)$$
Then $$\ln f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln f_k(x)$$
and thus
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{f_k'(x)}{f_k(x)}$$