# Proof that for any polynomial $f$, $\frac{f'}{f} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{X - x_i}$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

The problem is as follows:

> Consider the polynomial $ f = X^4 - 3X^3 + X + 7 \in R[X]$. Calculate $ \frac{1}{2-x_1} + \frac{1}{2-x_2} + \frac{1}{2-x_3} + \frac{1}{2-x_4} $, where $x_i$ represent $f$'s roots.

The official solution only states that for any polynomial $ f $, $\frac{f'}{f} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{X - x_i}$, where $ f' $ is the first derivative of $ f $. Thus the answer should be $ \frac{f'(2)}{f(2)} = \frac{-3}{1} = -3$.

Why is this so? I tried proving it, but to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relation between the roots of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660247/relation-between-the-roots-of-a-function)

Comment: @MartinR Yes, thank you. The only issue I see with that question is that it's not clear enough. If anyone else stumbles across this problem, I believe the way I presented it is much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ are the roots (not necessarily distinct) of a monic polynomial $f$, then $$f = (X-x_1)(X-x_2) \cdots (X-x_n).$$ Thus $$
\log f = \log(X-x_1)+\log(X-x_2)+\cdots+\log(X-x_n)
$$ and differentiating both sides we get $$
\frac{f’}{f} = \frac{1}{X-x_1} + \frac{1}{X-x_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{X-x_n}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: by the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), $f(X)=\prod_{i}(X-x_{i}).$
Then, by the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule),
$$
f^{\prime}(X)=\sum_{i}\prod_{j\neq i}\left(X-x_{j}\right).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $$f=(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n), $$ then $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x-x_i}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j\not =i}(x-x_j)}{(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n)}=\frac{f'}{f}.$$
To visualice the numerator equality see for example that the derivative of $$\left((x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)\right)'=(x-x_2)(x-x_3)+(x-x_1)(x-x_3)+(x-x_1)(x-x_2),$$ just extend the argument to any $n$ by induction by the product rule.